# Unix text parsing

Tags: bash, parsing, unix, grep

I have a text file in which may have multiple lines of text. Exactly one line of text will have the following sequence:

```
XMLcpLINK: ########
```

where the sequence of #'s can be any character or symbol.

What I need to do is read each line until I find `XMLcpLINK:` and save the sequence after it into a variable. Can anyone point me to sufficient UNIX references to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like

```
my_var=$(sed -n 's/XMLcpLINK: //p' file.txt)
```

should do it.

Here's a decent [`sed` reference](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html).

Or if you have `GNU grep`:

```
my_var=$(grep -oP '(?<=XMLcpLINK: ).*' file.txt)
```

Adding `-m 1` to `grep` is a good idea **ajozwik** has there, it should speed it up a little.

Answer (score 1):

`grep -m 1 'XMLcpLINK' file.txt | awk '{ print $2}'` - only first occurency

`grep 'XMLcpLINK' file.txt | awk '{ print $2}'` - all matching

Comment: You never need to pipe `grep` into `awk`. Do `awk '/XMLcpLINK/{print $2;exit}' file` and `awk '/XMLcpLINK/{print $2}' file` instead.

Answer (score 1):

## POSIX sh

No external commands or subshells

```
while IFS=': ' read name value; do
    case "$name" in
        XMLcpLINK) result="$value"
    esac
done < input_file
echo "$result"
```

Answer (score 1):

You got some good answers already but there is room for some improvement.

All the following print value of `XMLcpLINK` and then quit:

With `awk`:

```
$ awk '/^XMLcpLINK: /{print $2;exit}' file
########
```

With `grep`:

```
$ grep -Pom1 '(?<=^XMLcpLINK: ).*' file
########
```

With `sed`:

```
$ sed -n '/^XMLcpLINK: /{s/XMLcpLINK: //p;q}' file
########
```

Pick your favorite and use command substitution to store the result into a variable:

```
$ var=$(awk '/^XMLcpLINK: /{print $2;exit}' file)

$ echo $var
########
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
VAR=$(grep "XMLcpLINK: " test.txt | awk '{ print $2 }')
echo $VAR
```

test.txt being the file to analyse.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to achieve this:

With bash and dash, the following should work, with your testfile named 'myfile.txt'

```
while read i; do if [ "$i" != "${i#XMLcpLink: }" ]; then variable="${i#XMLcpLink: }"; break; fi; done <myfile.txt ; echo variable == "${variable}"
```

For explanation of the "${var#something}" see the 'Parameter Expansion' section in the bash man page.

Or a little shorter, perhaps faster (unless the file has many nonmatching lines after the match), and if you don't mind a space prefixed to the variable, using the external grep and cut utilities:

```
variable="`grep -e '^XMLcpLink: ' myfile|cut -d':' -f2-`" ; echo variable == "${variable}"
```

There are probably many more ways, possibly some bettery ways to do it.